# Python + selenium + firefox proxy does not work

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

I run Firefox alone, set up the agent, can work properly. I run Firefox via selenium, set the proxy, but it does not work! Proxy server is the same!

Code 1:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

    use_proxy=agent_IP+':'+str(agent_Port)

    _proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': use_proxy,
        'ftpProxy': use_proxy,
        'sslProxy': use_proxy,
        'noProxy': None, # set this value as desired
        "proxyType":"MANUAL",
        "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect":False
        })
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=_proxy)
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Code 2:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", True)
    profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", agent_IP)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(agent_Port))
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', int(agent_Port))
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', agent_IP)
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whater_useragent")
    profile.update_preferences() 
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Can someone help me?

thx！

Comment: After setting up the proxy through selenium, I found in the firefox inside the set of agents is correct, the same as the manual set!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 14):

I also encountered the same problem, the two methods I have tried, indeed are all invalid. But then a feasible way was found.

```
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

PROXY = "58.216.202.149:8118"

firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get(url)
```

It's run success for me.
It is important to note that：don't to set `noProxy` with `None` or `''`, delete it.
Look at a more detailed description of my blog: http://www.itfanr.cc/

Comment: Nice! This is the only solution that worked for me. setting profile didn't work.

Comment: @sanandrl Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that I got my setup working using the below configuration,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

user_agent = "Some UserAgent String here..."
proxy_ip = "123.123.123.123"
proxy_port = "12345"

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", str(proxy_ip))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", str(proxy_ip))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", str(proxy_ip))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", str(proxy_ip))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)

profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

profile.update_preferences()
binary = FirefoxBinary("/usr/bin/firefox")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary)

driver.get("https://ifconfig.me")

driver.save_screenshot("check_ip.png")
driver.quit()
```

So simply setting the HTTP proxy to all other protocols got it working.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This won't work for selenium v4.12.0 because the constructor of firefox selenium won't accept the profile argument anymore

Comment: @J_P thanks for your comment. I had a quick look and according to the changelog of selenium Python client, it appears that `firefox_profile` was moved under `moz:firefoxOptions`; see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1337b209bea0de5e8c13326c5c1f88eb8bfcde38/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/options.py#L110) and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1337b209bea0de5e8c13326c5c1f88eb8bfcde38/py/CHANGES#L668).

Comment: Of course this is only relevant if someone still wants to use the `firefox_profile`, but you could rather use the `capabilities` directly as explained in the other answer. I will try to update this answer if I get a chance soon; it's been ages =D. Thanks!

Comment: `capabilities` parameter is [deprecated](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1337b209bea0de5e8c13326c5c1f88eb8bfcde38/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L43) as well. only `options` is available